# How to remove CRLF blanklines

Tags: sed

I have a log file that has blank spaces and I would like to remove them, however, in some cases real loglines end with CR and some end with CR LF.

How can I sed/awk/TR the blank lines that have CR LF and no text? I have added the returns to each line below to show you how it looks in Notepad++.

I Tried the following command, however, it's in some cases removing last charters from other log lines.

```
sed -i "s/.$//" %Logs%\%DIR1%/%FILENAME1
```

Turns this

```
08-22 08:54:53.612 I/SystemServer(  760): StartUserManagerServic
08-22 08:54:53.612 I/SystemServiceManager(  760): Starting com.android.server.pm.UserManagerService$LifeCycl
08-22 08:54:53.613 I/SystemServer(  760): InitAttributerCach
```

Into this

```
08-22 08:54:53.612 I/SystemServer(  760): StartUserManagerService
08-22 08:54:53.612 I/SystemServiceManager(  760): Starting com.android.server.pm.UserManagerService$LifeCycle
08-22 08:54:53.613 I/SystemServer(  760): InitAttributerCache
```

Example: log with CRLF added. Trying to remove the blank spaces without cutting off the real loglines

```
08-22 09:13:42.018 D/TESTAPP( 7560): <<< Server Application info >>> <CR><LF>
08-22 09:13:42.018 D/TESTAPP( 7560): Name: Subscription<CR><LF>
08-22 09:13:42.018 D/TESTAPP( 7560): Package: com.bla.bla2<CR><LF>
08-22 09:13:42.018 D/TESTAPP( 7560): Version Name: 1.0.32.47<CR><LF>
08-22 09:13:42.018 D/TESTAPP( 7560): Version Code: 32<CR>
<CR><LF>
08-22 09:13:42.019 I/TESTAPP( 7560): (95): Upgrade for Subscription is not available<CR>
<CR><LF>
08-22 09:13:42.020 W/TESTAPP( 7560): (95): Unable to get the information of ccom.bla.bla as it is not installed<CR>
<CR><LF>
08-22 09:13:42.021 W/TESTAPP( 7560): (95): Unable to get the information of com.bla.bla as it is not installed<CR>
<CR><LF>
08-22 09:13:42.023 W/TESTAPP( 7560): (95): Unable to get the information of com.bla.bla<CR>
```

Comment: ISTM your data has lines ending CRLF  and others CRCRLF, so I'd suggest `sed s/\x0d\x0d\x0a/\x0d\x0a/g` should do the job.

Comment: Are you running in a DOS environment? Do you care how the non-blank lines end?

Comment: @Magoo, This did not work

    sed -i "s/\x0d\x0d\x0a/\x0d\x0a/g" test.log
or
    sed "s/\x0d\x0d\x0a/\x0d\x0a/g" test.log > test_new.log

Comment: Try `sed -e s/\x0d\x0d\x0a/\x0d\x0a/g test.log >newfile.txt` . Actually, `sed -e s/\x0d\x0d/\x0d/g test.log >newfile.txt` should do the same thing. Regrettably, "did not work" doesn't communicate much.

Comment: Yea that also did not work

Comment: Here is the file if you want to have a look. Its just adb logcat to file on a windows PC.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7olfkMi8BeQQTVtUFQ5NlQxc00/view?usp=sharing

Comment: `sed -b -e s/\x0d\x0d/\x0d/g test.log >newfile.txt` - the `-b` switch should set binary mode.

Comment: This seem to work

`sed "s/\r//" test.log > newfile4.txt`

Answer (score 0):

sed -i "s/\r//" test.log will fix the issue where you have CR CRLF